# Maven error package weblogic.wsee.jws.jaxws.owsm does not exist

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jdeveloper

We created client for web-service with security policy to call the other web-service by passing the required information like username,password and other information..Jdeveloper had given the support for security policy and their packages but to create the war and building the application we are using maven.
when we compile through maven it is giving the compilation errors.

Can any one suggest is there any plug in to add in the maven to compile the code..

Please click below link to see the image of compilation error :

[Compilation errors in console when we run Maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/774KZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Package weblogic.wsee.jws.jaxws.owsm is part of weblogic middleware and is installed on the modules folder.
You can add it to your maven repository for example Nexus as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
  <artifactId>ws.api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The file is %MW_HOME%\modules\ws.api_1.1.0.0.jar

or, of course, if you don't want the hassle of going through adding artifacts to the repository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws.api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${mw.home}/modules/ws.api_1.1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```